# some thing wrong with my mvim. when I type mvim or mvim in my terminal it shows up like this

Tags: vim

when I type mvim in my terminal it shows up something like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 31: import: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 32: import: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 37: flags: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 38: -Wall,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 39: -Wextra,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 40: -Werror,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 41: -Wno-long-long,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 42: -Wno-variadic-macros,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 43: -fexceptions,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 44: -DNDEBUG,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 47: -DUSE_CLANG_COMPLETER,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 54: -std=c++11,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 59: -x,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 60: c++,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 61: -isystem,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 62: ../BoostParts,: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 63: -isystem,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 66:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers,: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 67: -isystem,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 68: ../llvm/include,: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 69: -isystem,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 70: ../llvm/tools/clang/include,: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 71: -I,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 72: .,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 73: -I,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 74: ./ClangCompleter,: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 75: -isystem,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 76: ./tests/gmock/gtest,: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 77: -isystem,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 78: ./tests/gmock/gtest/include,: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 79: -isystem,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 80: ./tests/gmock,: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 81: -isystem,: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 82: ./tests/gmock/include,: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 83: ]: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 96: compilation_database_folder: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 98: syntax error near unexpected token `compilation_database_folder'
/usr/local/bin/mvim: line 98: `if os.path.exists( compilation_database_folder ):'
```

thanks alot!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Looks like mvim has been aliased. What does `alias mvim` shows

Comment: None of that exists in `mvim`.